# Can't pass CollectionProxy object to ActiveJob

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job, rails-activejob

I need to mark a collection of messages at the background (I am using delayed_job gem) since it takes some time on the foreground. So I've created an `ActiveJob` class `MarkMessagesAsReadJob`, and passed it `user` and `messages` variables in order to mark all of the `messages` read for `user`.

```
// passing the values in the controller
@messages     = @conversation.messages
MarkMessagesAsReadJob.perform_later(current_user, @messages)
```

and in my ActiveJob class, I perform the task.

```
// MarkMessagesAsReadJob.rb
class MarkMessagesAsReadJob < ActiveJob::Base
  queue_as :default

  def perform(user, messages)
    messages.mark_as_read! :all, :for => user
  end
end
```

However, when I tried to perform the task, I got the error 
**ActiveJob::SerializationError (Unsupported argument type: ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy):**

I read that we can only pass supported types to the ActiveJob, and I think it can not serialize the CollectionProxy object. How can I workaround/fix this?

**PS:** I considered

```
@messages.map { |message| MarkMessagesAsReadJob.perform_later(current_user, message) }
```

however I think marking them one by one is pretty expensive .

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the easy way is pass message ids to the `perform_later()` method, for example:

in controller:

```
@messages = @conversation.messages
message_ids = @messages.pluck(:id)
MarkMessagesAsReadJob.perform_later(current_user, message_ids)
```

And use it in `ActiveJob`:

```
def perform(user, message_ids)
  messages = Message.where(id: message_ids)
  messages.mark_as_read! :all, :for => user
end
```

Comment: This is a pretty nice and performance-friendly solution. Thanks!

Comment: @BurakÖzmen my pleasure, Happy coding!

Comment: messages = Message.where(id: message_ids)

Answer (score 6):

For larger data sets, passing the message_ids is impractical.  Instead, pass the SQL for the messages:

```
@messages = @conversation.messages
MarkMessagesAsReadJob.perform_later(current_user, @messages.to_sql)
```

then query them from the job:

```
class MarkMessagesAsReadJob < ActiveJob::Base
  queue_as :default
  def perform(user, messages_sql)
    messages = Message.find_by_sql(messages_sql) 
    messages.mark_as_read! :all, :for => user
  end
end
```

Comment: This is clever (as in "I wish I'd thought of it"). The risk I suppose is that the set if IDs returned by the SQL changes, but then if the SQL represents the way in which you want the objects to be selected then that's actually a good thing. Excellent stuff.

Answer (score 4):

Because the job will be executed later, I think we should pass ids as parameter instead a collection

ActiveJob need serialize parameter, and SerializationError will be thrown if parameter type isn't supported
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveJob/SerializationError.html

ex:

```
@message_ids = @conversation.messages.pluck(:id)
# use string if array is not supported
# @message_ids = @message_ids.join(", ")
MarkMessagesAsReadJob.perform_later(current_user, @message_ids)
```

then query those messages again and mark it

```
class MarkMessagesAsReadJob < ActiveJob::Base
  queue_as :default
  def perform(user, message_ids)
    # use string if array is not supported
    # message_ids = message_ids.split(",").map(&:to_i)
    messages = Message.where(id: message_ids) #change this to something else
    messages.mark_as_read! :all, :for => user
  end
end
```

not tested , hope that it will be ok