# Delayed::Job losing active record relation, but instead array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, delayed-job

I am having a Job class for sending Email. I am passing the collection (active record relation object, lets say `@payments = Payment.where(status: 'pending')` to the argument of Mailer class.

```rb
Delayed::Job.enqueue(
  EmailJob.new(
    company: current_company,
    type: :payments,
    collection: @payments # Payment::ActiveRecord_Relation
  ),
  target: 'Payment Email',
  company: current_company
)
```

The problem I am facing is, When the worker picks the Job, the collection is considered as just an `Array` of payments, I am expecting this as an activerecord collection object so that I can do some stuffs over those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ActiveJob supports the following types of arguments by default:
>
> - Basic types (NilClass, String, Integer, Float, BigDecimal, TrueClass, FalseClass)
> - Symbol
> - Date
> - Time
> - DateTime
> - ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone
> - ActiveSupport::Duration
> - Hash (Keys should be of String or Symbol type)
> - ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess
> - Array
> - Module
> - Class
>
> - [Rails guides: Active Job Basics](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html#supported-types-for-arguments)

When you pass an `ActiveRecord::Relation`, Rails will serialize it by casting it into an array as its not a supported type. ActiveJob does use GlobalId to pass individual records though so it seems like a better option is probally just to create an association or some other method to fetch the payments in your job given a company.

See also [Can't pass CollectionProxy object to ActiveJob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32154220/cant-pass-collectionproxy-object-to-activejob)
.